# ClassNotFoundException with Class.forName("int")

Tags: java

Please note that I can't get forName() to work **specifically with "int"**. 
On the other hand, it works alright with a class I created in the same package as

```
Class.forName("mypackage.dummyclass")
```

Is that something to do with fully qualified names? I've tried "java.lang.int" and "java.lang.integer", but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `java.lang.Integer`, with an upper-case I.

Comment: I would strongly advice not to do so. What makes you do that?

Comment: `Class.forName` is for class objects, `int` is primitive data type, `Integer` is wrapper class

Comment: @DorianGray Just got confused working through somebody else's example that generates classes on the fly. Will change to int.class now that I'm clear as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for getting the `Class` object associated with primitive types, like `int`, is

```
int.class
```

Likewise, you use `byte.class`, `long.class`, `boolean.class`, etc. for the other primitive types.

While there's a special relationship between `int` and `java.lang.Integer`, `int.class` is not the same thing as `Integer.class`.

Note that **you cannot use `Class.forName` with a primitive type name**.

As documented in [the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html):

> **Class.forName()**
> If the fully-qualified name of a class is available, it is possible to get the corresponding Class using the static method `Class.forName()`. This cannot be used for primitive types.

And from the same tutorial, on how to use the `.class` syntax with primitives:

> **The .class Syntax**
> If the type is available but there is no instance then it is possible to obtain a Class by appending ".class" to the name of the type. This is also the easiest way to obtain the Class for a primitive type.
>
> `boolean b;`
> `Class c = b.getClass();   // compile-time error`
> `Class c = boolean.class;  // correct`

Comment: but still i'm not able to access at using `Class.forName()`

Comment: @Deadpool That's right, you can't use `Class.forName("int")` for that, that's why Java gave a special syntax for that. `int.class` is what you're looking for, why do you want to use `Class.forname`? Are you loading classes from dynamic names/strings?

Comment: `Class.forName()` must work for all the classes and interfaces, so curious that `int` has class and it is not working for that, i'm curious to know why? either those classes are written in some other Native languages ?

Comment: @ernest_k I just __thought__, since I can do int.class, that same class could be accessed through forName. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a primitive type in Java, not a class, so try `java.lang.Integer` instead (which is not exactly the same thing but is interchangeable for many purposes)

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName` is for class objects but `int` is primitive data type.

Try `java.lang.Integer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive data type, not a class. Integer class can be used for int. So you should use "Integer".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `java.lang.integer`, try `java.lang.Integer` (With Capital `I`)

---

The above will work because, `Class.forName()` tries to create an object of the full class name passed as `String` arg in it.

`java.lang.Integer` - This is a class

`int` - This is not a class. It is a primitive data type. Hence, failing.